# I want to Check two patterns in two consecutive line and delete the first line if the second pattern matches in the following line

Tags: awk, sed, delete

I want to Check two patterns(a1 and a2) in two consecutive line and delete the first line(line having pattern a1) if the second pattern(a2) matches in the following line

Input

```
a1
b1
a1
a2
c1
c2
a1
b1
a1
a2
```

Output

```
a1
b1
a2
c1
c2
a1
b1
a2
```

Comment: please add more details, pattern is rather fuzzy, I can't understand how and when `a1` should be kept (or skip)

Comment: if a1 follows a2 then a1 needs to be removed otherwise not.

Comment: What if there's `a1`, `a1` and `a2` in sequence? Should both `a1`s be removed?

Comment: in my problem case removing one a1 would do, which precedes a2.

Comment: See [how-do-i-find-the-text-that-matches-a-pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65621325/how-do-i-find-the-text-that-matches-a-pattern) to understand the issue and then replace the word "pattern" with regexp-or-string + full-or-partial + word-or-line-or-other everywhere in your question.

Answer (score 1):

With `sed`, you would do an `N;P;D` cycle to process two lines together like this:

```
sed 'N;s/a1\na2/a2/;P;D'
```

Comment: sed 'N;s@<uld>@\n</uld>@</uld>@;P;D'
output from shell
sed: -e expression #1, char 20: unknown option to `s'

Comment: My pattern are in actual pattern1="<uld>" pattern2="</uld>". How to incorporate this pattern ?

Comment: Why do you add additional `@`? You only need `s@pattern@replacement@`. Your error message is because of the characters following the third `@`. `sed 'N;s@<uld>\n</uld>@</uld>@;P;D'` should work if there are no additional characters other than those patterns.

Answer (score 0):

How far would

```
awk '/a1/ {T = $0; getline; if (!/a2/) print T} 1' file
```

get you?

Comment: This fails in scenarios where the second line is `a1` (`a1\na1\n\a2\n` as a minimal test).